# If this less 0.50% set it to 1%

Tags: jquery

[DEMO is HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/L5GmR/)

if vitamins have less 0.50% it's not visible for user...
need change to 1%

well in demo you see this bug

```
var summary_count = 0;
$('.vitamins .vitamin .count').each(function(){
    summary_count += parseFloat($(this).text());
});

$('.vitamins .vitamin').each(function() {
    var this_count_raw = parseFloat($(this).find('.count').text());
    var this_count = parseFloat(this_count_raw / summary_count * 100);
    $('<span></span>').appendTo($(this)).css('width', '0').wrap('<div class="vitamin_amount"></div>');
    $(this).find('.vitamin_amount span').animate({width: + this_count + '%'}, 2000);
});
```

Thanks for help)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Math.max`:

```
width: Math.max(this_count, 0.5) + '%'
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L5GmR/2/**

Changing anything less than 0.5 to 1.0 will make 0.1 appear larger than 0.7, which probably isn't what you want.

This'll also make it impossible to display `0`, so you may want to do something like this instead:

```
width: (this_count < 0.2 ? 0 : Math.max(this_count, 0.5)) + '%'
```

Comment: :) first example it's what i need)

Answer (score 2):

`Math.ceil(this_count)`

This will round everything up; if you only need to round up **0**.5%, then add an if statement.